# Bigcommerce - Get Product Custom Field

Tags: api, custom-fields, bigcommerce

I wanted to use the Bigcommerce API from [here](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/stores/v2/products/custom_fields) , and fetch all custom product fileds, so I used this get path:

GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}.

Bacause I needed {store_hash} I visited this [site](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/legacy/basic-auth) , and creted "Legacy API Account" and created in admin panel legacy api account and generated: Api path and Api token.

I thought that the store_hash is the same as api token, but it wasn't.

What am I do now, how does look like the full path to using this clause :
for "OAuth" :
GET /stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}.
or for "Basic Auth" :
GET /api/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}

In this way, I would like to do:
$.getJSON( "/stores/{store_hash}/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}", function( data ) { // custom code with data });

Thank you in advance for any help
Paul

Comment: bigcommerce have to ways to build apps: private apps(Legacy API Account - into the admin) and public apps(OAUTH - Generating Access Token)

Answer (score 0):

If you're just using the legacy API you can request directly from the store's API path.

```
$.getJSON( "https://store-XXXXX.mybigcommerce.com/api/v2/products/{product_id}/custom_fields/{id}")
```

If the store has their own private SSL installed that API address will be their domain instead of the .mybigcommerce address